# How can I create a new series by using specific rows and columns of a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am working with a pandas data frame which looks like as follows:

```
       title         view_count comment_count like_count    dislike_count   dog_tag cat_tag bird_tag other_tag  
0   Great Dane Loves     299094        752.0      15167          58           [dog]    []       []   [] 
1   Guy Loves His Cat    181320       1283.0      13254         262             []  [cat]       []   []
```

Basically, title represents the name of the YouTube video. If the video is about dogs, you can see [dog] under dog_tag category. If it is not about dogs, you see an empty list [] under dog_tag.

I need to do create a new series which include title, view_count, comment_count, like_count and dislike_count for every row of dog_tag **if the value of dog_tag is [dog]**. I should not include any information for the rows where the value of dog_tag is [].

So, my new series should seem like this:

```
       title         view_count comment_count like_count    dislike_count   dog_tag     
0   Great Dane Loves     299094        752.0      15167          58           [dog]     
1   Dogs are Soo Great!! 181320       1283.0      13254         262           [dog]
2   Dog and Little Girl  562585       5658.3      46589         121           [dog]
```

Is there any ***genius person*** who can solve this problem? I tried the following solutions that I found on Stack Overflow but I could not get what I need :(

```
only_dog = [dodo_data.loc[:, dodo_data.loc[0,:].eq(s)] for s in ['dog_tag', 'view_count', 'comment_count', 'like_count', 'dislike_count','ratio_of_comments_per_view', 'ratio_of_likes_per_view']]

dodo_data.loc[:,dodo_data.iloc[0, :] == "dog_tag"]
dodo_data.loc[:,dodo_data.iloc[0, :] == "view_count"]
dodo_data.loc[:,dodo_data.iloc[0, :] == "comment_count"]
```

Comment: `only_dog = data.loc[dog_tag == ['dog'], columns_to_select]` should just do the trick

Comment: I receive an error message which says "Too many indexers"

Comment: `columns_to_select` has to be a list of column names. I assume that's what is causing your error

Comment: @LukasThaler - it not working, because list

Comment: @LukasThaler I have already done exactly the same thing you mentioned and received the "too many indexers" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if convert empty list to boolean get `False` you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by condition and also by list of columns names:

```
cols = ['title', 'view_count', 'comment_count', 'like_count', 'dislike_count', 'dog_tag']
df = df.loc[df['dog_tag'].astype(bool), cols]
```

Comment: Awww, I noticed that I have a problem :( I had two more columns that I did not share in order to simplify the question. One is "ratio_of_comments_per_view" and the other one is "ratio_of_likes_per_view". I also added them to cols like the others, but it is written "NaN" in each row of them. What might be the reason?

Comment: @Reyhan - what is `print (df.columns.tolist())`  before my solution?

Comment: @Reyhan - because one reason for missing values are some whitespace for column name like `'ratio_of_likes_per_view '`. Or maybe missing values in original, test it by `print (df.loc[df['dog_tag'].astype(bool)])`

Comment: ['title', 'view_count', 'comment_count', 'like_count', 'dislike_count', 'dog_tag']

Where is the other two column names? I swear I added them :(

Comment: @Reyhan - what is `print (df.columns.tolist())`  before my solution, not after ;)

Comment: ['title', 'id', 'publish_date', 'view_count', 'comment_count', 'like_count', 'dislike_count', 'tags', 'dog_tag', 'cat_tag', 'bird_tag', 'other_tag', 'ratio_of_comments_per_view', 'ratio_of_likes_per_view'] Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @Reyhan - No poblem. If test `print (df.loc[df['dog_tag'].astype(bool)])` there are missing values in new added columns like `ratio_of_likes_per_view` ?

Comment: @Reyhan - Test it before my solution

Comment: Okay, I rerun all the code and I can see all values now. No NaNs! OMG, thanks a ton @jezrael

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import io
dff=io.StringIO("""title,view_count,comment_count,like_count,dislike_count,dog_tag,cat_tag,bird_tag,other_tag 
Great Dane Loves,299094,752.0,15167,58,[dog],[],[],[] 
Guy Loves His Cat,181320,1283.0,13254,262,[],[cat],[],[]""")  

df2=pd.read_csv(dff)

df2 = df2[df2['dog_tag'] == '[dog]']
df2 = df2[df2.columns.drop(list(df2.filter(regex=(r'_tag(?<!dog_tag)'))))]
```

Comment: name io is not defined, according to python :(

Comment: added the import, that's just to read in my csv based on your data. It might just work on it, depending on the == statement